# cannot locate haarcascade default frontal face XML file on windows

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I am new to image processing and i've been getting my hands dirty with opencv for python for past few weeks. Today I tried to use the default haarcascade XML file for the face detection. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

front_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = front_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 6)
#for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
#    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 155), 3)

print faces

cv2.imshow('frame', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Problem here is that it prints out an empty set. And to my surprise when I change the name of the XML file to something like 'aaa.xml', it still produces the same output. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you say `front_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`, the cascade file must be present in the same folder in which the program is being executed, Best practice is to pass the full qualified path of the cascade file, If you are not able to locate the cascade files bundled with opencv then you can also download the `.xml` files from [this link](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades).

And then you may load the haarcascde by passing in the full qualified path:

```
front_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/Users/anmoluppal/Downloads/cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Comment: Hi ZdaR, I tried all possible ways to get XML file using cv2.CasecadeClassifier but could not fix this issue. Below is the sample code:                                                                                                   
           import numpy as np 
           import cv2
           face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("C:/Users/u/haarcascade_default.xml")
              if type(face_cascade) is not 'cv2.CascadeClassifier':
                    print(type(face_cascade))
                    raise Exception("no classifier found at this path")         any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For those trying to find it under a Windows conda environment this helped me locate the cascade files.

Using the CMD prompt:

```
dir %CONDA_PREFIX% /s /a /b | findstr /i haarcascade
```